# Function not working when used in a select

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am using the following function to remove all extra white space from a string:

```
CREATE FUNCTION RemoveSpaces
(
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Amit Singh
-- Description: Remove extra spaces from string
-- Usage:       SELECT dbo.RemoveSpaces('Code  Jotter')
-- =============================================
    @str AS VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,' ','{}'),'}{',''),'{}',' ')
END
```

The function works fine. But when I try to use the function in a `SELECT` statement, the string remains intact.

```
SELECT TOP 1
      dbo.RemoveSpaces(sms_message)
  FROM MyTable
```

I receive the same value as `sms_message` without the extra spaces removed.

Comment: Can you provide a sample value of `sms_message` where you see this faulty behavior?

Comment: @vkp I don't think trim functions remove spaces from "An (space) (space) (space)  example".

Comment: What you see as spaces in the message string are not real spaces.  Your code should work.  For instance, your code works in SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0c7c/1.

Comment: This function would be an excellent candidate to become a table valued function instead of a scalar. It will perform better and be far more flexible.

Comment: The code you have here replaces multiple spaces with a single space. It does NOT remove all spaces.

Comment: @SeanLange he said `extra white space` so i assume that's his purpose..

Answer (score 0):

You are over thinking it. All you need to do is replace any double space with a single space. The solution is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION RemoveSpaces
(
-- =============================================
-- Author:      John Sacharok
-- Description: Remove extra spaces from string
-- Usage:       SELECT dbo.RemoveSpaces('Code  Jotter')
-- =============================================
    @str AS VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
    (REPLACE(@str,'  ',' ')
END
```

If you want to include TAB as something you are replacing, then the code below works better. The second replace is for a TAB rather than a space.

```
CREATE FUNCTION RemoveSpaces
(
-- =============================================
-- Author:      John Sacharok
-- Description: Remove extra spaces and tabs from string
-- Usage:       SELECT dbo.RemoveSpaces('Code  Jotter')
-- =============================================
    @str AS VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
    REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,'  ',' '),'    ',' ')
END
```

Comment: Seems the OP is trying to remove instances where 2 or more spaces occur in sequence to keep only 1 space so that only necessary spacing is retained. As noted by gordon, it is far more likely he's got some other whitespace that is keeping his function from working since it works fine for spaces alone.

Answer (score 0):

Your data needs cleansing, it may have special characters? - incorporate into your stored proc or update the column via below

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(YourColumn, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided examples and the successful examples of it working for spaces, the problem here appears to be your source table has other white-space characters besides just spaces causing the problem.

Here's some sample code you can use within your function to replace all whitespace (started with list from wikipedia of ascii characters) and uses a better replacement token than "{" and "}" by using non-printable ascii characters instead.

```
DECLARE @WhiteSpace VARCHAR(500) =
    CHAR(32) -- Space
    + CHAR(9) -- Tab
    + CHAR(10) -- Line feed
    + CHAR(11) -- Line tab
    + CHAR(12) -- Form feed
    + CHAR(13) -- Carriage return
    + CHAR(133) -- Next line
DECLARE
    @i INT = 1,
    @Delim CHAR(2) = CHAR(17) + CHAR(18), -- Replaces "{}"
    @DelimRev CHAR(2) = CHAR(18) + CHAR(17) -- Replaces "}{"
WHILE @i <= LEN(@WhiteSpace) BEGIN
    SET @str = REPLACE(@str, SUBSTRING(@WhiteSpace, @i, 1), @Delim)
    SET @i = @i + 1
END
SET @str = REPLACE(REPLACE(@str, @DelimRev, ''),@Delim, ' ') -- With just space
```

Comment: @PedRam Please feel free to upvote an answer if it helped you and accept it if it solved your question. This helps others to know which answers may have helped with your question. It also increases your reputation.